# Sorting locations by distance from a given point and filtering the results by a maximal distance in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a collection in which each document has a location. I need to sort the documents by their distance to a given starting point. Moreover, I would like to have only the documents whose distance from the starting point doesn't exceed a certain limit.

I have tried the following:

```
Store.geo_near([32,32]).where(:geo_near_distance.lt => 2) 
# all docs whose location are at most 2 from [32, 32]
```

The above results in the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for #<Mongoid::Contextual::GeoNear:0x438fb70>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by: Mongoid6

```
  Store.unscoped.where(
     :coordinates => {
       '$nearSphere' => your_store.coordinates,
       '$maxDistance' => distance_in_km.fdiv(111.12)})
```